# undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000003a27a58>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

First, I do really apologize, since I'm still newbie on this.

I was trying to install Fat Free CRM by following the instruction on this following sites:

http://www.blogdugeek.fr/crm-installation-fat-free-crm-debian-squeeze/

http://guides.fatfreecrm.com/Setup-Linux-or-Mac-OS.html

As I follow the instructions, I've encounter some errors and resolved some. However, upon executing this command:

> RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create db:migrate crm:settings:load

I was stuck in this command line and here are the following errors that I've been stuck with:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000003a27a58>
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:150:in `resolve_all'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in `configurations='
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

As I've search for more related issue, I found some, but it's still no use.

Also, here are some data that might be needed:

**Ruby Version**

ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-linux]

**Rails Version**

Rails 4.2.6

**Here are the error lines**

***connection_specification.rb***

```
 def resolve(config)
      if config
        resolve_connection config
      elsif env = ActiveRecord::ConnectionHandling::RAILS_ENV.call
        resolve_symbol_connection env.to_sym
      else
        raise AdapterNotSpecified
      end
    end

    # Expands each key in @configurations hash into fully resolved hash
    def resolve_all
      config = configurations.dup
      config.each do |key, value|               <---- Error line
        config[key] = resolve(value) if value
      end
      config
    end
```

***connection_handling.rb***

```
    class MergeAndResolveDefaultUrlConfig # :nodoc:
  def initialize(raw_configurations)
    @raw_config = raw_configurations.dup
    @env = DEFAULT_ENV.call.to_s
  end

  # Returns fully resolved connection hashes.
  # Merges connection information from `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` if available.
  def resolve
    Error line ---->    ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification::Resolver.new(config).resolve_all 
  end

  private
    def config
      @raw_config.dup.tap do |cfg|
        if url = ENV['DATABASE_URL']
          cfg[@env] ||= {}
          cfg[@env]["url"] ||= url
        end
      end
    end
```

***core.rb***

```
def self.configurations=(config)
    Error line --->     @@configurations = ActiveRecord::ConnectionHandling::MergeAndResolveDefaultUrlConfig.new(config).resolve
  end
  self.configurations = {}

  # Returns fully resolved configurations hash
  def self.configurations
    @@configurations
  end
```

***databases.rake***

```
db_namespace = namespace :db do task :load_config do
Error line ---->   ActiveRecord::Base.configurations       = ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.database_configuration || {}
ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths = ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.migrations_paths
```

Here's the ***config/database.yml*** file.

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MySQL driver:
#   gem install mysql2
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
development:&development
  adapter:mysql2
  encoding:utf8
  database:fat_free_crm_development
  pool:5
  username:root
#  password:
  socket:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *development
  database: fat_free_crm_test

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: fat_free_crm_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
 socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

staging:
  <<: *development
  database: fat_free_crm_staging
```

Hope to hear and seek some advises and learning.
If there's need some more information, let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: Could be an error in `config/database.yml`. Post that file please.

Comment: You did a good effort on debugging the error, but you forgot to inspect the data near the error line. You would probably have solved the error by yourself already if you'd added `require "pp"; pp config` into `connection_specification.rb` just before the error line. Remember this trick for the future.

Comment: Please don't post additional files as answers. Just edit the original question and add it to the end.

Comment: Sorry, done editing. :)

Comment: Sorry for the trouble again sir Casper. Regarding with this where should I put the `require "pp"; pp confing` ? Before the `config = configurations.dup
      config.each do |key, value| ` or in between the .dup and .each? sorry for being newbie. :(

Comment: I formatted it correctly for you here. Compare it to your own version and see where the mistakes are: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f91b6a49f525fe79426a8e8e81f132e7

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `database.yml` is the problem. YAML requires a separator between the key and data.

So not like this:

```
production:
  adapter:mysql
  encoding:utf8
  ...
```

But like this:

```
 production:
   adapter: mysql
   encoding: utf8
   ...
```

You need to correct all the lines in the file, because you have this error everywhere.

Comment: Sorry, for the trouble sir, as I've edited the database.yml the error is occurring upon executing this command line **RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create db:migrate crm:settings:load**

Comment: Post the edited `database.yml` file (delete the old one from your question, then paste the new version into the question). You probably have an error in there somewhere still.

Comment: @Peter You still have errors in the file. You have to edit ALL lines. `development`, `test`...all of them. If you even have a single line with a missing space then the file won't load properly.

Comment: sir, I've done editing the line and validate on http://www.yamllint.com/ . However, upon running the Rails command I do still have the same issue. Also, I've edited the database.yml on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `database.yml` file again. Don't add anything
ie the file format must be correct. 
 had unkowngly comment a line on to that was causing the error.